# "probability of a probability": confusion with categorical and real-value random variables

Tags: probability, categorical-data, conditional-probability

I think I'm having a "probability of a probability" issue but I don't know how to resolve it:

Let's say a variable $l_0$ can take values ${A,B,C}$. I have $N$ training samples $i$ from two different populations ($d \in \{0,1\}$) with probability profiles 
$$p(l_i = A \mid d_i)=a,~p(l_i=B \mid d_i)=b,~p(l_i=C \mid d_i)=c=1-a-b.$$ Until now, I was averaging these probabilities to get

$$ p(l_0 = A \mid d_i) = 1/N \sum_i p(l_i=A \mid d_i) $$

and the same for $B,C$. So basically, I only consider the mean probabilities in the training data instead of the entire distribution, which I think might be more appropriate.

Now let's consider a different scenario where we only have one category $A$: if $v_{0} = p(l_0 = A)$ is not really considered a probability anymore, but some score, we can assume $v_0$ is normally distributed with $\mu, \sigma$ learned from the training data:

$$ p(v_0 \mid d_i) \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_{d_i}, \sigma_{d_i}) $$

My question is, how can I combine these two scenarios? Ideally I would want my categorical variables to follow a sort of gaussian distribution, but at the same time I would need all my categorical probabilities to sum to 1.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. Do you mean that you observe a number of pairs $(l_i, d_i)$ where $l_i$ is your variable of interest and $d_i$ is the class that $l_i$ belongs to? And now you have some new point $(l_0, d_0)$ and you want to estimate the probabilities that $l_0 = A$ given $d_0$ and etc for $B$ and $C$?

Comment: Also the Dirichlet distribution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution may be much more appropriate for your $v_0$

Comment: @Chaconne Actually, I want to estimate $d_0$ given $l_0$. You might be right about the Dirichlet distribution, thanks!